# Implication of probabilistic ordering from convergence in probability

Tags: probability, solution-verification, borel-cantelli-lemmas

For a sequence $X_1, X_2, \ldots X_n$ with $E X_n = a$ I proved that $X_n \to_p a$, i.e.
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}P(|X_n - a|>\varepsilon)=0
$$
Does this type of convergence imply a probabilistic  $ordering$ on the sequence, i.e.
$$
P(|X_1-a|>\varepsilon) > P(|X_2-a|>\varepsilon)> \ldots > P(|X_n-a|>\varepsilon)
$$
This would be useful for deriving a lower bound, e.g. for proof of convergence a.s., e.g. if $P(|X_1-a|>\varepsilon) = \pi$, the sum of probabilities is lower-bounded by $n \pi $ and hence diverges.

Intuitively it makes sense, but it sounds a bit too general and simplistic, hence probably wrong, but I couldn't find a good explanation anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly false. In such questions it is always advisable to look at constant random vaiables. If something is not true for  a sequence of real numbers it cannot be true for a  sequence of random variables.

Take $X_n=\frac1  n$ if $n$ is even and $X_n =\frac  1 {4n}$ if $n$ is odd. Then $a=0$. Take any $\epsilon  $ between $\frac  1 4$ and $\frac  1 2$. Then $P(|X_1-a| >\epsilon)=0$ and $P(|X_2-a| >\epsilon)=1$.

Comment: Yeah I thought so: seems suspiciously easy